# In Django admin, how to filter users by group?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-authentication

It gives you filter by staff status and superuser status, but what about groups?

Answer (score 13):

Since version 1.3 it can be done [using this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter):

```
list_filter = ('groups__name')
```

Of course as @S.Lott explains you must register your customized class in the admin.py file:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class MyUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    list_filter = UserAdmin.list_filter + ('groups__name',)

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, MyUserAdmin)
```

Comment: Nice, thanks! But it shows up as "By name" followed by the list of groups, which is a bit confusing, it would be better if it said "By group"

Comment: I agree with @thnee. It can be achieved like this `list_filter = ('groups',)`

Answer (score 5):

See [Customizing an Admin form in Django while also using autodiscover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471550/customizing-an-admin-form-in-django-while-also-using-autodiscover)

Essentially, you define a customized Admin class with the features you want.

Then unregister and register your revised Admin class.

```
admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, MyUserAdmin)
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a complete example, that inherits from SimpleListFilter, which is available in Django 1.4 and up (current as of May 2023):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter

It support setting all available labels and parameters to create the completely custom filter.

It shows up as "By group" in the filter panel, with a list of all available groups.

```
from django.contrib.admin import SimpleListFilter
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _

class GroupListFilter(SimpleListFilter):
    title = _('group')
    parameter_name = 'group'

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        items = ()
        for group in Group.objects.all():
            items += ((str(group.id), str(group.name),),)
        return items

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        group_id = request.GET.get(self.parameter_name, None)
        if group_id:
            return queryset.filter(groups=group_id)
        return queryset

from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class MyUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    list_filter = UserAdmin.list_filter + (GroupListFilter,)

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, MyUserAdmin)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I've been searching for

Answer (score 3):

In later versions of Django, it works exactly as you'd expect:

```
list_filter = ('groups', )
```

No need to unregister/register the admin class.

Comment: And where might I put that?

Comment: In the admin.py for the app that contains your User model.

Comment: But you don't get a user-customizable admin.py for `django.contrib.auth` so a good place to do this override is in your custom User model's admin.py.

Comment: I don't _have_ a custom user model.

Comment: Ah! In that case you can do it in any of your models, using the unregister/register techniques above. I was only recommending your User model because I assumed you had one, but Django actually doesn't care where you do it.