# Changing User ModelAdmin for Django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

How do you override the admin model for Users? I thought this would work but it doesn't?

```
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name')
    list_filter = ('is_staff', 'is_superuser')

admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

I'm not looking to override the template, just change the displayed fields & ordering.

Solutions please?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You have to unregister `User` first:

```
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name')
    list_filter = ('is_staff', 'is_superuser')


admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

Maybe this question is also interesting for you: [Customizing an Admin form in Django while also using autodiscover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471550)

Comment: @second: In a file called `admin.py` in the particular application., see also http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/contrib/admin

Comment: extend `ModelAdmin` doesnt work for me.  I tried extending from `UserAdmin` then my CustomUserAdmin works

Comment: You must extend the UserAdmin otherwise user creation and updating will not funtion properly.

Answer (score 12):

Update tested with Django 3+

So you don't lose data like password encryption and the form itself, perform the import below

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
```

Define an AdminCustom class as the example and customize with the options you want, overriding the default.

```
class UserAdminCustom(UserAdmin):
   list_display = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser')
   list_filter = ('is_staff', 'is_superuser')
   search_fields = ('username', )
```

And in the end, follow the example mentioned

```
admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdminCustom)
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer, however if you already have AUTH_USER_MODEL set to a custom user model, than "admin.site.unregister(User)" should be omitted.

Answer (score 4):

As pointed by @haifeng-zhang in the comments, it is useful to extend the default UserAdmin instead.

The official documentation about this can be found here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


# Define a new User admin
class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    list_display = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name')
    list_filter = ('is_staff', 'is_superuser')

# Re-register UserAdmin
admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```