# Django Allauth filter "Email addresses" in Admin

Tags: django, django-allauth

I'm using django-allauth and I have a question. In order to filter the data in my adminsite for my User model I use following code:

```
def get_queryset(self, request):
    qs = super(UserAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
    if request.user.is_superuser:
        return qs
    return qs.filter(profile__country=request.user.profile.country)
```

It lets the adminusers (not superusers) only see the tables from users in their country.

I would also like to filter the data in the standard column created by allauth called "Accounts" - > "Email Addresses" but I don't know which queryset that would be. I would be thankful for any tip.

Have a nice day guys!

Solution here: ->

admin.py looks like this :

```
from allauth.account.models import EmailAddress
from allauth.account.admin import EmailAddressAdmin


class CustomAllauthAdmin(EmailAddressAdmin):

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(EmailAddressAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return qs
        return qs.filter(user__profile__country=request.user.profile.country)

admin.site.unregister(EmailAddress)
admin.site.register(EmailAddress, CustomAllauthAdmin)
```

Comment: You want them to only be able to see email addresses for users in their own country?

Comment: Yes for example only users in their own country.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it's a third party app, you'll first need to override its admin in your own admin.py. Check the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9321955/where-do-i-modify-the-admin-view-code-for-a-3rd-party-app) for an example.

As for the queryset, you inspect the allauth model for the EmailAddress model. It links to users using a 'user' field. So, you would chain your query like so:

```
 qs = super(EmailAddressAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
    if request.user.is_superuser:
        return qs
    return qs.filter(user__profile__country=request.user.profile.country)
```