# How to imitate new app in Django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I have few models in my Django app. How do I imitate another app to create app section for one of my models in admin interface?

Comment: what did you mean by imitating?

Comment: When you create new app and register models in it, you see new section for this app in admin panel. I want to make new section without creating new app

Comment: Register your models with admin.site.register(your model). https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [AdminSite](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/_modules/django/contrib/admin/sites/#AdminSite) is responsible for creating the index page. The process is as such:

1. `_build_app_dict` builds a dictionary containing various data (including model._meta.app_label) of all models registered with the given site
2. `get_app_list` turns that dictionary into a list sorted by app label and by model (verbose) name
3. the `index` method/view adds that app_list to the template context
4. the template (specified by AdminSite.index_template) is rendered

If all you want to do, is alter the appearance of the index page (say by adding a 'fake' app to group your models differently), creating a [custom AdminSite](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#customizing-the-adminsite-class) and hooking into any of the four steps above might be a cleaner way than messing with the internal app registry.

Answer (score 1):

You can try changing the `app_label` of your models you want to move:

```
class Meta:
    app_label = 'new_section'
```

Just make sure to adapt the FK and M2M fields accordingly.
See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33856716/2528658).