# How to change the Django admin filter to use a dropdown instead of list?

Tags: django, django-admin

If, for a field that you want to filter by, you have more than ~10 values, the filtering sidebar starts to be ugly and harder to use.

I'm looking for a solution to replace the `<li>` with a dropdown selection (combobox) or something similar that will solve the same problem.

Comment: have you looked at django-grappelli? it looks like there is exactly what you want, so you can look and see how it's done.

Answer (score 65):

Thanks @beholderrk, @gediminas and @jk-laiho! I packaged this into a [reusable app](https://github.com/mrts/django-admin-list-filter-dropdown).

Install:

```
pip install django-admin-list-filter-dropdown
```

Enable in `settings.py`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'django_admin_listfilter_dropdown',
    ...
)
```

Use in `admin.py`:

```
from django_admin_listfilter_dropdown.filters import (
    DropdownFilter, ChoiceDropdownFilter, RelatedDropdownFilter
)

class EntityAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    list_filter = (
        # for ordinary fields
        ('a_charfield', DropdownFilter),
        # for choice fields
        ('a_choicefield', ChoiceDropdownFilter),
        # for related fields
        ('a_foreignkey_field', RelatedDropdownFilter),
    )
```

Here's what it looks like:

[image: Screenshot of dropdown list filter]

Comment: is there any way to filter selected fk for a model ?

Comment: @mujad, yes, see RelatedDropdownFilter in the example above and in the docs.

Comment: @PrateekGupta, can you be more precise? What did you try, what happened? Please file an issue in the [GitHub project](https://github.com/mrts/django-admin-list-filter-dropdown) if the issue is real and reproducible.

Comment: @mrts I followed the steps as u mentioned that is first installed it using pip then added it to INSTALLED_APPS and at last added to the admin.py but still there were no dropdown in the filter section..

Comment: @PrateekGupta, this is not detailed enough. I can help you if you open an issue in the GitHub project, StackOverflow comments are not suitable for support discussions.

Comment: @PrateekGupta, note that you need to have more than 4 choices in the list for the dropdown to appear.

Comment: @PrateekGupta If you have a new or follow-up question about this answer, please ask a new question.

Comment: @CodyGray No its fine :)

Answer (score 41):

I cannot comment answers so I'll add to beholderrk's answer here.

1. create a new template called `dropdown_filter.html` or similar
2. copy the code of filter.html from feincms to `dropdown_filter.html`
3. create a new filter class in `filters.py`:

   ```
   from django.contrib.admin.filters import AllValuesFieldListFilter

   class DropdownFilter(AllValuesFieldListFilter):
       template = 'admin/dropdown_filter.html'
   ```
4. now you can use this filter in your admin class:

   ```
   class SomeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
       # ...
       list_filter = (('country', DropdownFilter),)
   ```

Works great!

Comment: Perfect answer. Worked for me in Django 1.8. Thanks!

Comment: Excellent. I had to inherit from `RelatedFieldListFilter` instead when filtering based on a foreign key, but the same template worked.

Comment: Similarly to JK Laiho, I had to inherit from `ChoicesFieldListFilter` for a field with a `choices` kwarg. Using `AllValuesFieldListFilter` did work, but it displayed the values instead of the human-readable names.

Comment: for me results is always empty, and DropdownFilter display not dropdown....

Answer (score 33):

Use filter.html from feincms

```
{% load i18n %}
<script type="text/javascript">var go_from_select = function(opt) { window.location = window.location.pathname + opt };</script>
<h3>{{ title }}</h3>
<ul class="admin-filter-{{ title|cut:' ' }}">
{% if choices|slice:"4:" %}
    <li>
    <select style="width: 95%;"
        onchange="go_from_select(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
    {% for choice in choices %}
        <option{% if choice.selected %} selected="selected"{% endif %}
         value="{{ choice.query_string|iriencode }}">{{ choice.display }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
    </select>
    </li>
{% else %}

    {% for choice in choices %}
            <li{% if choice.selected %} class="selected"{% endif %}>
            <a href="{{ choice.query_string|iriencode }}">{{ choice.display }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}

{% endif %}
</ul>
```

Comment: For anyone running into this: this is the correct approach as of this writing, but see Gedas' answer for more details.

Comment: This is a great answer.  To correct the previous comment's typo, use @Gediminas answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20900314/1302095) which spells out the steps to achieve this.

Comment: Also, one can add a "Remove" option for ease of getting back to the "All" option by adding the following between the last two lines (`{% endif %}` and `</ul>`): ```{% with choices.0 as all_choice %}{% if not all_choice.selected %}<strong><a href="{{ all_choice.query_string }}">x {% trans 'Remove' %}</a></strong>{% endif %}{% endwith %}```.  I find having a "remove" link much less finicky than having to pick "All" in the dropdown.

Answer (score 4):

An easy option would be to use [django-grappelli](http://grappelliproject.com/), which replaces all the filters with drop downs.

Comment: most overkill response i've ever seen :) no-offense :+1:

Answer (score 3):

You can copy the admin templates from the django installation into you templates/admin folder in your project.

Then you will need to do any of 2 things in the forms or templates you want to show your outputs in:

1. If you are working with a form, in that you would like the list choices to be posted back to a database, you would in your model.py, on the field you have your choices, put in some this like this:

   ```
   choice = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.Select(choices=CHOICES))
   ```
2. If it is just to display on a page, then you will output on a template tag something like this:

   ```
   <select>
     {% for choices in object.details.all %}
       <option> {{ object.choice }} </option>
     {% endfor %}
   </select>
   ```

Answer (score 2):

I am not a fan of all solutions provided up to now.

Why? If, for a field that you want to filter by, you have more than 10 values, a listview box isn't that handy, too. I advice to use the standard search field capability of django admin which will show you a search field:

```
class BooksAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('ISBN', 'title')         
    search_fields = ('ISBN',)
    # instead of: list_filter = ('ISBN',)
    ordering = ('title',)
```

Answer (score 1):

http://djangosuit.com/ also offers dropdowns for list filters.

Comment: Avoid djangosuit. I used it and now I'm stuck with django 1.8 and cannot update to the latest django without breaking everything.

Comment: suit has a version 2.0 (https://github.com/darklow/django-suit/tree/v2/),  that is compatible with django 1.11 (the newest stable version), and works fine as far as i can see, but so far lacks good documentation. Another option is to use django jet https://github.com/geex-arts/django-jet, which has also built-in autocomplete support (albeit not for filters, as far as i can see). This way you avoid overriding templates, which might become a problem when updating django

Comment: django-suit  is abandoned by the developer

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to create a new template in `admin/filter.html` and implement the HTML code suggested by @beholderrk. Just implemented it for a client and it works great.

Problem with `DropdownFilter and RelatedDropdownFilter` is that it loses the proper display. Instead of the translated strings for `Charfield(choices=xxx)`, it will show `True`, `False` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please give a complete example. it shows like before. 
here is my code

```
from django.contrib import admin
from pages.models import Post, Device, DeviceType, DeviceModel, Ipaddress, DeviceGroup, Location,Department,Comment
from django_admin_listfilter_dropdown.filters import DropdownFilter, RelatedDropdownFilter


class CommentInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Comment

class IpaddressAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('ipaddress',)}
#        model=Ipaddress

        search_fields = ['ipaddress', ]
#     
        list_display = ('ipaddress', 'machinename', 'user', 'department','location',)
        list_filter = (
        ('user', DropdownFilter),
        ('department', RelatedDropdownFilter),
        ('location', RelatedDropdownFilter),

    )
```

Here is the screenshot[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with the same problem some few weeks back. So this answer might be useful to some developers from the future. 
I managed to solve the problem by writing a custom `template.html`
I have bundled the code in an amazing package now that does the same for you, [here's the link](https://github.com/whoisashish/django-admin-searchable-dropdown).

---

### **Here's how you can implement a Searchable Dropdown in place of the default List:**

**1. Installation:**

```
pip install django-admin-searchable-dropdown
```

This command will install the latest version of the package in your project.
Now, include the package in your project by adding `admin_searchable_dropdown` to your `INSTALLED_APPS` inside `settings.py` file.

**2. Usage:**
Let's say you have following models:

```
from django.db import models

class CarCompany(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class CarModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    company = models.ForeignKey(CarCompany, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

And you would like to filter results in `CarModelAdmin` on the basis of `company`. You need to define `search_fields` in `CarCompany` and then define filter like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from admin_searchable_dropdown.filters import AutocompleteFilter


class CarCompanyFilter(AutocompleteFilter):
    title = 'Company' # display title
    field_name = 'company' # name of the foreign key field


class CarCompanyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ['name'] # this is required for django's autocomplete functionality
    # ...


class CarModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = [CarCompanyFilter]
    # ...
```

---

After following these steps you may see the filter as:

1. [This is how the list filter is rendered in the form of a dropdown when the package is used](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/whoisashish/django-admin-searchable-dropdown/main/admin_searchable_dropdown/media/UnFiltered.PNG)
2. [And the dropdown filter is also Searchable](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/whoisashish/django-admin-searchable-dropdown/main/admin_searchable_dropdown/media/Filtered.PNG)

### **Features Offered:**

1. If you have large fields in Admin Filter, the sidebar gets widened, this package provides you the same list in a dropdown format, hence, no such hassle.
2. If you have more than, say 20, field items, list filter is now a long side-pane, just ruining the admin interface. The Dropdown filter fixes that.
3. The Dropdown is also "Searchable", with an input text field (which utilizes Django's own `auto_complete` functionailty), so as long as the Django version you are using is greater than 2.0, you should be fine.
4. You can customize other `list_filters` you may have, like change the Title above the dropdown, or a custom Search logic etc.
5. You can customize Widget Texts to display in the Dropdown Option to use something other than the default `str(obj)`

Answer (score 0):

To add search functionality to @beholderrk and @Gediminas solution use the follow

Create `searchable_dropdown_filter.html` in `templates/admin` folder and paste the following code

```
{% load i18n %}
{% load static %}

<!-- Django's Select2 CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'admin/css/vendor/select2/select2.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'admin/css/autocomplete.css' %}">

<!-- jQuery (Django Admin uses this, so you can refer to it) -->
<script src="{% static 'admin/js/vendor/jquery/jquery.js' %}"></script>

<!-- Django's Select2 JS -->
<script src="{% static 'admin/js/vendor/select2/select2.full.js' %}"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.searchable-select').select2();
    });

    var go_from_select = function(opt) { window.location = window.location.pathname + opt };
</script>


<h3>{{ title }}</h3>
<ul class="admin-filter-{{ title|cut:' ' }}">
{% if choices|slice:"4:" %}
    <li>
    <select style="width: 95%;"
        onchange="go_from_select(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)"
        class="searchable-select"
    >
    {% for choice in choices %}
        <option{% if choice.selected %} selected="selected"{% endif %}
         value="{{ choice.query_string|iriencode }}">{{ choice.display }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
    </select>
    </li>
{% else %}

    {% for choice in choices %}
            <li{% if choice.selected %} class="selected"{% endif %}>
            <a href="{{ choice.query_string|iriencode }}">{{ choice.display }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}

{% endif %}
</ul>
```

In your `admin.py` or `filters.py` paste the following

```
from django.contrib.admin.filters import RelatedFieldListFilter

class SearchableDropdownFilter(RelatedFieldListFilter):
    template = 'admin/searchable_dropdown_filter.html'
```

In your admin implementation use it as follows

```
class SomeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # ...
    list_filter = (('country', SearchableDropdownFilter), ('city', SearchableDropdownFilter),)
```

This uses select2 to add search functionality to the dropdown. This is very handy when you have a ton of options you want to filter from.