# Django - format date filter values

Tags: django, django-admin, django-filter

Referring to this old thread [Use a dropdown instead of list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5429276/how-to-change-the-django-admin-filter-to-use-a-dropdown-instead-of-list). How do i format any date attribute used in the answer offered by beholderrk.

PS. I'm using v1.8

Answer (score -1):

you can use the django template filter date : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#date

Edit : here is a summary of the filter as people have suggested in the comments. Basically if you have a date variable in a django template you can apply the date filter to it to change its format.

to do it you just append the filter to your variable, something like variable|date "format", for example:

```
var|date "Y m d"
```

would result in 2016 10 19, the format reference is available in the documentation matching your django version

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.