# Django admin outputs ul for foreignkey instead of dropdown list

Tags: python, django

that is, instead of a drop-down list, the ul-li tag appears

```
class EpApplicationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'application_status', 'f_iin', 'f_phone', 's_iin', 's_phone', 'entity_bin', 'entity_grnz')
    list_per_page = 20
    search_fields = ["id__id", "f_iin", "s_iin", "f_phone", "s_phone"]
    list_filter = ('application_status__description', )
```

Comment: How do you create the dropdown?

Comment: Maybe this could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5429276/how-to-change-the-django-admin-filter-to-use-a-dropdown-instead-of-list