# Django user entitlements on creation / privilege escalation

Tags: django, authorization, administrator, entitlements, privilege-elevation

I got the following issue:
If I give a user staff-status and allow him to create users but not to create new groups and assign entitlements, he is still able to assign another user the 'admin'-entitlements - so he can easily add a user who has more entitlements than himself!
Has anyone found a way to avoid that without providing a custom user-model / -view?

I'm thankful for any response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django requires that users with permission `Can add user` have also the permission `Can change user`. Quoting the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/):

> Also note: if you want your own user account to be able to create users using the Django admin site, you'll need to give yourself permission to add users and change users (i.e., the "Add user" and "Change user" permissions). If your account has permission to add users but not to change them, you won't be able to add users. Why? Because if you have permission to add users, you have the power to create superusers, which can then, in turn, change other users. So Django requires add and change permissions as a slight security measure.

However, it might be possible to restrict the set of permissions available for a given user to assign by modifying the `ModelAdmin` (or its form). Here's [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/471661/520779) showing how to redefine the `UserAdmin`.

I believe your new `ModelAdmin` would have to: a) filter out users that have more permissions than you (so you can't **remove** permissions from them); b) modify the change user form so you can't set the `superuser` field and the permissions you're not allowed to assign are excluded from the list (or disable the whole list altogether - but I dunno that's what you really need, right? Creating an user with no permissions at all would be of little use IMO).

**Update:** Here's what I found so far. Should satisfy all goals above, except the permission filtering problem (it behaves like you asked in the question - deny assiging **any** permissions by users who are not entitled to). You can modify it to better suit your needs (for instance, replace `.is_superuser` by whatever logic you want to allow/deny changing permissions).

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class MyUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    def queryset(self,request):
        qs = admin.ModelAdmin.queryset(self,request)
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return qs
        # Only allow viewing/editing users who are not superusers
        return qs.filter(is_superuser=False)
    def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        # Deny editing groups, permissions and the superuser status
        return () if request.user.is_superuser else ('is_superuser', 'groups', 'user_permissions')

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, MyUserAdmin)
```

Comment: Note: I wish I could give you a more complete answer, but I'm having some trouble finding out how to properly customize the `UserAdmin` or its forms. I'll come back at this later if I find anything useful. (P.S. [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.0/ref/contrib/admin/#adding-custom-validation-to-the-admin) should be a good starting point)

Comment: Thank you _very_ much so far! Helps a lot, I think!